# Fixed information on header

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm using *iReport* and I need to make a report as follows:

A header that shows the information about the course and the informations about the students. Something like:

Course Name: Introduction to Logic
School: INT 
Number of Students: 50

Student 1   email1@email.com 
Student 2   email2@email.com
Student 3   email3@email.com
...

I don't think that a subreport would do what I want at the header.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can find here a lot of [samples](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference.html). [JasperReports Ultimate Guide](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/JasperReports-Ultimate-Guide-3.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

place all this information in separate report and import that report as a subreport in header.
It will works fine.

Comment: It did the job. Thanks.